# PySpark dataframe show() gives 'Unsupported class file major version 58' Error

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to read in from a mongo DB using pyspark and the mongo-spark connector. Reading in the data works fine, but when I try to see the dataframe with `df.show()` I get the error

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 58'
```

This is what my code looks like right now.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myApp") \
.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "...") \
.config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "...") \
.config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1') \
.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()

df.show()
```

Comment: Your Mongo Connector package version and spark version seem to be incompatible. Can you tell us what your spark version is?

Comment: Use Java 8 to run Spark.